# Filtrar Modelos na view Django

Tags: django, view, filter

Fala Galera

Tenho a seguinte app rodando em Django 1.6.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
ao clicar em cão ou gato a ideia seria apresentar uma página realizando a filtragem do objeto

O animal está modelado assim para filtrar:

```
    TIPO_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Cachorro'),
    (2, 'Gato')
)

tipo = models.IntegerField('Tipo', max_length=1, choices=TIPO_CHOICES)
```

Como seria minha view para manipular este tipo de exibição ?

```
def cao(request):
    cao = Animal.objects.filter(tipo__equal = Cachorro)
    template_name = 'Adota/cao.html'
    context = {
        'cao':cao
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Desde já agradeço o apoio, lembrando que estou no django 1.6

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais simples de você fazer isso é criar URLs e views diferentes pra cada um deles.

Digamos que você vai ter a URL `/cao/` e `/gato/`. Depois disso você também teria as views `cao` e `gato`.

```
def cao(request):
    caes = Animal.objects.filter(tipo=1)
    # ai aqui vai o resto do código que você já tem

def gato(request):
    gatos = Animal.objects.filter(tipo=2)
    # ai aqui vai o resto do código que você já tem
```

Lembrando que ali eu coloquei `1` porque no seu `TIPO_CHOICES` o que é salvo no banco é o primeiro valor, o segundo ele é utilizado apenas para exibição.